# sitecore 7 alias publish

Tags: permissions, sitecore, alias, publish

I'm working with sitecore 7 and the alias are working fine.

The only issue that I'm having is to grant publishing access to the authors/editors to the alias folder that is located under system (/sitecore/system). This location is apparently only accessible by the administrators (for obvious reasons).

Is there any way how to solve this issue without changing the publishing proccess or the workflow?
I thought about moving the alias folder outside the system but I'm not sure about the implications. I think is risky to move it as the website is already live.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do your editors publish content? Is it only through workflow or do they have access to the normal publish wizard? By default everything is published, regardless or read/write access (there is config option to override behaviour though) - so a smart publish would publish your aliases as well.

Comment: try adding "related=1" in workflow publish action and publish item on which alias is configured. If it doesn't work you can create your own publish action which will publish aliases of the item being published.

Comment: Currently they are publishing "manually" through the wizard - we are setting up the workflow but it will take a while as the roles/users are still being adjusted. Its a multi-site instance and users can't do a publish at the parent level - only admins.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to assign your users to the "Analytics Maintaining" role, which has read and write permissions on the Aliases folder.

Comment: Thanks Gregorius, I'm not working in that project anymore but I'll keep your suggestion in case I come across the same issue.